# kick user out in sshrc

Tags: ssh

I have seen tutorials for reporting suspicious logins (from the wrong IP) using `/etc/ssh/sshrc`.
I would like to take it to the next level and kick out those users (close the ssh session immediately).

I have tried exit (doesn't work) and logout (rejected: /etc/ssh/sshrc: line 16: logout: not login shell: use "exit").

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to kill session.
First list session

```
netstat -tanp
```

The PID to kill is in the right hand column.

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I get the PID associated with the current session being established ?

Comment: When you do `netstat -tanp` you will get rows `tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xx.5:59579      xxx.xxx.xx.7:22         ESTABLISHED 25212/ssh` . Number before `25212/ssh` is the PID for session to my pc from xxx.xxx.xx.7:22

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I meant: Let's say there are many legit ssh sessions established. I want to block the **current** one from sshrc. How can I know which one it is?

Comment: You habe ip address. After killing of session you can add deny rule to firewall.

Comment: Oh, you mean that I should do something like `kill -9 \`netstat -tanp |grep ${IP} |awk {print$xxx}\`` ?

Answer (score 3):

The PID you want to kill is the parent of the shell running the sshrc script.

In other words,

kill -TERM $PPID

in the sshrc script will kill the parent of the sshrc script, which is also the process that is trying to become the ssh session of the user.

No need to kill -KILL (which also works): the ssh session is perfectly able to listen to more gentle requests to be terminated.

Comment: Looks like you know core of problem, but please add more details to your answer.. Some moderators can flag it like low quality, coz is no direct answer.

Comment: It _is_ a direct answer: to terminate the session you want to kill the parent process of the shell interpreting the sshrc script. I've added the exact command to use to avoid the "exercise left to the reader".